# Pootle - issues exporting properties files

Tags: java, python, localization, translation, pootle

I am using pootle for localization.

I imported source translations from Java properties files.

the property file looks like:

```
STR_TEXT1 = Hello
```

Than I imported other language files. I paid translators to translate those other languages.
Now I need to export those translations from pootle back to JAVA property files.  Problem is, that it randomly exports it to UTF8 other time to to \uXXXX escape Encoding.  There is no way how to setup the encoding for export files.  Second problem is, that those export files are corrupted. It renders them like many rows without problem and some rows are cut, like this:

```
STR_TEXT1 = HELLSTR_TEXT2 = bye
```

Than I accidently deleted property files from /po/my_project directory.  When I did this, exports stoped to work. But all translations are still wisible on the pootle web.  So, i suppose those translations are saved in some other files, maybe mo files.  Is there a way how to get those translations to java property files? how to force pootle to replace those original texts from original property files by fresh texts from pootle?

Answer (score 0):

Pootle should export you files as Latin1 not UTF-8, it will escape non-Latin characters using \uXXXX syntax.  Newer Pootle's allow you to export in UTF-8.

The best is to attach your source and translated files to a bug over at [bugs.locamotion.org](http://bugs.locamotion.org/) so that the Pootle developers can look at your source files.

The translations are kept in a database.  Pootle makes use of you template file usually en.properties to create translated versions. I haven't tested what happens if you delete this template file.